# Free en-GB dictionary for spell check in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, spell-checking

I'm trying to use the [Vectorlight](http://www.vectorlight.net) spell checker for Silverlight. The demo code comes with the en-US.dic file, but I'm trying to find a compatible one for British English.

I have found one [here](http://en-gb.pyxidium.co.uk/dictionary/mozilla.php) but it doesn't work. The format seems similar to the en-US one, but it just doesn't work (i.e. it doesn't suggest any words).

Comment: I've got both of these however there looks to be a job of work to massage the en-GB dictionary into the format that Vectorlight is using.  I'd be really interested if someone else has already done this work. ;)

Comment: Ah, you and me both then! Do you understand what's missing from the en-GB version?

Comment: I've also got this task to do soon. Hopefully I'll find a simply solution as it's just an Aspell file

Comment: Actually I don't much mind which spell check component I use, and I don't mind buying one, but I've been evaluating Telerik's suite of Silverlight components which I really like, but they're missing a spell check!!!! Grrrr! On the other hand, Infragistics has a spell check, but I don't like the rest of their components so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

According to a reply on the [VectorLight](http://www.vectorlight.net/forums/liquid_components/671-where_can_i_find_an_en-gb_dictionary_for_spell.aspx) forum you can use the en-GB dictionary that comes with the [NetSpell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/files/) project on SourceForge.

Comment: One observation I'd make now is that even though I can get the VectorLight spellcheck to work with en-GB, there's still a big chunk of work to do to make it into a viable spellchecker. As it stands, it only checks single words, so there would be a lot of development to do to build a spellcheck dialog, allow customisation of the dictionary, etc.